# Ignite 2.7 issue while upgrading java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.h2.util.LocalDateTimeUtils.LOCAL_DATE

Tags: ignite

HI while upgrading to ignite 2.7 we face this issue , this hapepns when ignite is about to start certain custom caches.

```
2019-01-09 19:28:04.260 UTC [SERVER] [exchange-worker-#38%fdap%] [ERROR] [,] ROOT - Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.h2.util.LocalDateTimeUtils.LOCAL_DATE from class o.a.i.i.processors.query.h2.H2DatabaseType]]
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.h2.util.LocalDateTimeUtils.LOCAL_DATE from class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2DatabaseType
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2DatabaseType.fromClass(H2DatabaseType.java:147)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.dbTypeFromClass(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2972)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.createTable(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2873)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerType(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2809)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.registerCache0(GridQueryProcessor.java:1633)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart0(GridQueryProcessor.java:805)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:866)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1330)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:2165)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCachesOnLocalJoin(GridCacheProcessor.java:2023)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.initCachesOnLocalJoin(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:924)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:766)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2667)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2539)
```

There is a ticket also for the same https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-10612 , will this be solved or is there a release guide on how to overcome the issue .

Please help ...

Comment: Could you please attach the cache configuration.

Comment: @PavelVinokurov was a dependency issue (due to another version of H2 ) its resolved now . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have correct version of H2 dependency? For AI 2.7 it should be `com.h2database` `h2` `1.4.197` and not any other. The error you have posted is linkage error which will arise from having incorrect library version in classpath.

Comment: Yes was a issue with h2 dependency coming from another project dependency . Its working now thanks .

Answer (score 2):

by putting

```
<properties>
    <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
</properties>
```

works to resolve this.
since the default of h2 is 1.4.199 which can cause other exceptions. you have to override that as well.